# Custom css styles

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to store custom attributes in css settings?

Suppose I want to store some metadata like:

```
.some_class {
    customAttribute: "metadata value";
}
```

And then retrieve this metadata using jquery:

```
alert($("div.some_class").css("customattribute")); 
// Outputs message "metadata value"
```

Comment: Why not use an attribute inside the HTML tag itself? `<div class="some_class" attribute="value">`

Comment: Depending on doctype this is not the prefered way. Since it won't validate.

Comment: Making up your own CSS properties won't validate either.

Comment: @SiteSafeNL CSS provides wider abilities. For example, we can change some code of class in css file and this changes will be propagated on all DOM elements which are referenced to that class.

Comment: @PeeHaa So, which doctypes support that?

Comment: @Eliah: sorry my mistake. Just don't do it! Use the solution I provided in my answer. Doctype is repsonsible for validating HTML and not CSS. Was more @SiteSafeNL

Comment: In css that wouldn't be a good thing to do, but have you seen LESS? (http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.data()`.

Example:

```
$('.elem').data('customattr', 'value');
```

And retrieve it using:

```
$('.elem').data('customattr');
```

Or if you want to store it in the HTML.

Use HTML5's data attr:

```
<div class="elem" data-customattr="value">
```

HTML5's custom attributes always start with `data-`

Comment: PeeHaa, thank you for your reply. Unfortunatelly data() method doesn't provide what I need. Look at my comment above.